# Asp.net web api and SignalR publish

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a web api that gets realtime data from IoT device. My data is geographic coordinates (lon,lat)

```
public class DataController: ApiController{
    public IHttpActionResult Post(Location loc){
        // save loc to database.
    }
}
```

in this first scenario, I am saving databse. So I have a client application that has a map. and I want to show incoming locations on my map as realtime.

But SignalR has a separated Hub class.

```
public class DataPublisherHub : Hub
{
    public void PublishCoordinates()
    {
        // I want to send all clients incoming locations that web api action.
        //????
        Clients.All.sendAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood but you can create a static function in your hub like this :

```
public class DataPublisherHub : Hub
{
    public static void PublishCoordinates(string lat, string long)
    {
        // I want to send all clients incoming locations that web api action.
        //????
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<DataPublisherHub>();           
        context.Clients.All.sendLatLong(lat,long);
    }  
}
```

and call it from your post function like this :

```
public class DataController: ApiController{
    public IHttpActionResult Post(Location loc){
        // save loc to database.
        DataPublisherHub.PublishCoordinates(loc.lat,loc.long)
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

Dont forget to implements the `OnConnected()` function in your hub to get all existing data in the database :

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
  //Get all datas from db  
  foreach (var data in datas){
       Clients.Caller.sendLatLong(data.lat,data.long);
  }  
  return base.OnConnected();              
}
```

Comment: static hub methods does not find on client side.

Comment: They are working well, can you put some code to check where is your issue (client side too). EnableDetailedErrors can help too : `var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration { EnableDetailedErrors = true };
 app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);`

Answer (score 0):

Your client application should first of all subscribe itself to the server signalR Subscribe() method where you can add it to some group like below.

```
public void Subscribe(long clientId)
    {
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, clientId.ToString());
    }
```

Then, after saving your coordinates to the database, call the PublishCordinates() method in the hub like:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(Location loc)
{
    // save loc to database.
    DataPublisherHub.PublishCordinates(loc);
}
```

Change the PublishCordinates() method like:

```
public void PublishCoordinates(Location loc)
{
    try
        {
            var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<DataPublisherHub>();
            context.Clients.Group(clientId.ToString()).Recieve(loc);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return;
        }
}
```